# Calculate $\tan\theta\cot\beta$ from the image below.

Tags: trigonometry

> Calculate $\tan\theta\cot\beta$ from the image below.
>
> [image]

This was asked in a university admissions exam. This is meant to be a tricky question for trigonometry wizards.

Apparently, the standard definition of $\cot(\beta)=x/y$ is valid only when the angle starts from the positive side of the $x$-axis. In this question, both angles don't start from the positive side of the $x$-axis.

Please provide a detailed reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

The tangent $\space (\tan)\space$ is the ratio of the opposite side to the adjacent side in a right triangle.

The cotangent $\space (\cot)\space $ is the reciprocal of the tangent. It is the ratio of the adjacent side to the opposite side in a right triangle.

It is easy to see that we have:

$$\cot \beta = \frac{4}{3}, \space \tan \theta = \tan(90°+ \alpha) = - \cot \alpha = -\frac{4}{3}.$$

Hence:

$$\cot \beta \cdot \tan \theta = - \frac{16}{9}.$$

**Figure:**

[image]

Comment: I wonder if the calculations in your figure imply that the angles 126.87 and 36.87 start from the positive side of the x-axis. By the way, all the possible answers in the admission exam were positive numbers. I will wait for another answer or until Wednesday to post a solution I found and I would appreciate your comments.

Comment: The figure clearly shows what are the measures of angles $\beta$ and $\theta$. Next, for angles which belongs to II. and IV. quadrant we know that tangens and cotangents are both negative...

Comment: This is a solution from people who teach trigonometry to applicants who prepare to sit the admission exam at that uni. The only explanation I can think of is that the standard definitions tan(m)=y/x and cot(n)=x/y are used in the solution but angles must start from the positive side of the x-axis otherwise calculations may be wrong.. Here it is:   cot(pi/2+θ)=(-4)/(-3) but cot(pi/2+θ)=-tan(θ) so -tan(θ)=(-4)/(-3) so tan(θ)=-4/3. Similarly: tan(-pi/2+β)=(-4)/(-3) but tan(-pi/2+β)=-cot(β) so -cot(β)=(-4)/(-3) so cot(β)=-4/3. Final answer: tanθcotβ=(-4/3)(-4/3)=16/9. Is that a correct procedure?

Comment: To @MathsAl123: Please note, in mathematics, one cannot tolerate any ambiguity. I will still vote for my answer :)